# How to deploy WCF service with Entity Framework to IIS?

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, iis-7.5

I currently copy web.config, SVC file and a bin folder with all the compiled code. This is sufficient for non-DB operations to work. However, I get errors whenever I call any operation which has EF entities.

The web.config file contains a valid connection string. How should I deploy the edmx file?

Also, instead of this manual deployment, is there an alternate way to build a deployment package that will take care of DB upgrades as well if needed?

I tried the "Publish" option but that is not very intuitive.

I am using .Net 4.0, VS2010, IIS7.5, SQLServerExpress 2008R2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are know MSBuild, if you know MSBuild in deep, you can write MSBUILD script to accomplish all the tasks.

1 - For Entity framework. On deployment server, you need to install Entity framework 4 or the version that you are using.

2 - DB upgrade is a strategy. So you need to think about this. Better create a DB project in Visual studio and it will simplify some of the stuffs.